# Forge Viewer - Failed to display edges in Settings for DWF/DWFX model

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm now developing a web application to view my DWF/DWFX models (exported by Revit 2017/2019). I'm now using the most updated version of forger viewer api (v6).

I discovered that it failed to display edges in Settings. When I switch back to use v4.2 version of the viewer api, the problem disappeared. The edges are showing correctly. I have also tried the same models but in different formats (RVT & NWD), there are no such problem. Is it a bug for v6? Where can I report the bug?

[image: display edges setting]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you describe, it does sound like a bug in v6. Please send us an email to forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com, including as much info as possible:

1. specific version of the viewer (you can find it by typing `LMV_VIEWER_VERSION` in the console)
2. any errors/warnings from the console
3. screenshots of what you see
4. if possible, the input file that reproduces the issue

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also had a non-visible edge issue and Michael Beale suggested me an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934819/1435514) on another post.

I'll summarise it. As I was creating my viewer instance via Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D directly, rather than the Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication, there is a magic configuration parameter that you will need to apply when initializing the Forge viewer, so that the lines appear and the `Settings -> Performance -> Display edges` toggle becomes operational.

To fix it, an extra option isAEC: true must be passed into the options when you are loading your model:

```
viewer.loadModel(svfUrl, {isAEC:true}, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
```

Hope it helps you or someone else.