# Forge Viewer fails to display edges

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, viewer

I used https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless as a starting point for my Forge React application and I modified `viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D(viewerElement, {});` to `viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(viewerElement, {});` to change it back from a headless to a classic viewer.

I can load my model but it appears without edges and when I go to `Settings -> Performance -> Display edges` it is off by default, and when I try to set it back the edges stay invisible.

From my non wokring viewer:
[image: Screenshot with Display edges off]
[image: Screenshot with Display edges on]

When I try the same operation with the same model loaded on [Autodesk Viewer](https://autodeskviewer.com) it works as expected and I can toggle the visibility of the edges.

From the [Autodesk Viewer](https://autodeskviewer.com)
[image: Screenshot with Display edges off]
[image: Screenshot with Display edges on]

I found another [seemingly related question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984588/forge-viewer-failed-to-display-edges-in-settings-for-dwf-dwfx-model), but I tried `viewer.js?v=v4.2`, `viewer.js?v=v5.0` and `viewer.js?v=v6.3.1` and I still have the invisible edges issue.

I also posted a [Github Issue](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless/issues/28)

Thank you for your help.

Alexis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, if you are creating the viewer instance via 
Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D directly, rather than the 
Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication, then there is a magic configuration parameter that you will need to apply when initializing the Forge viewer, so that the lines will appear...

To fix it, an extra option 
`isAEC: true` must be passed into the 
modelOptions in your code, see below:

```
var modelOptions = {
    placementTransform: mat,
    globalOffset:{x:0,y:0,z:0},
    sharedPropertyDbPath: doc.getPropertyDbPath(),
    isAEC: true //!<<< Here is the missing line
};

viewer.loadModel(svfUrl, modelOptions, onLoadModelSuccess, onLoadModelError);
```

Comment: Thank you Michael, Magic indeed.
The Github starter I used [viewer.load](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-react-express-headless/blob/1a632a9f84a807f2dec2e935aaca0dfcb5ada242/src/components/Viewer/Viewer-helpers.js#L85), but switching to `viewer.loadModel` and adding `{isAEC:true}` solved my problem with no discernible side effect.