# Forge Viewer : Turning "Display Edges" per model instead of Global settings

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We are displaying an architectural Revit model and adding a fairly detailled site context.

In the Forge Viewer Settings I can turn On or Off "Display Edges" globally.

[image]

However we'd like to have the Edges "On" for the Revit Model but "Off" for the context. Is there a way to achieve this?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932378/forge-viewer-fails-to-display-edges) and I tried to load the site model with:

```
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables,{
                placementTransform: m.matrix,
                keepCurrentModels: true,
                globalOffset: {x:0,y:0,z:0},
                isAEC: false //!<<< Tried this to prevent Edges
            })
```

But it did not change anything and it still depends on the Global settings.

I found another setting and also tried the following but no luck either:

```
   const models = viewer.impl.modelQueue().getModels()
   const contextModel = models.filter(m => m.loader.svfUrn === contextURN);
   if (Array.isArray(models) && models.length) {
        models[0].hasEdges = false;
   }
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which model format of your road model is, but passing the `createWireframe: false` option should help turn off the model edges with my research.

```
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, bubble, {createWireframe: false, keepCurrentModels: true})
```